# Context Per Request: How to update Entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I have a repository class as shown below. There is a method to get entity object – GetPaymentByID. I am retrieving a Payment object and making a change to its PaymentType property. But this is not reflected in databse. I know the reason – the SaveContextChanges method uses a new context.

I need to use **Context Per Request** approach. Hence I am creating new context in each method.

In this scenario, how can I modify the code to successfully update the database?

Note: The client program should not use the ObjectContext because the **repository can be changed with another repository that does not use Entity Framework**.

**Note**: "*A DataContext is lightweight and is not expensive to create*"

```
namespace MyRepository
{


public class MyPaymentRepository
{
    private string connectionStringVal;
    public MyPaymentRepository()
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        sqlBuilder.DataSource = ".";
        sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = "LibraryReservationSystem";
        sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;

        // Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
        EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
        entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ToString();
        entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/MyEDMtest.csdl|res://*/MyEDMtest.ssdl|res://*/MyEDMtest.msl";

        connectionStringVal = entityBuilder.ToString();
    }




    public MyEntityDataModelEDM.Payment GetPaymentByID(int paymentID)
    {
        MyEntityDataModelEDM.Payment payment;
        using (var myObjectContext2 = new MyEntityDataModelEDM.LibraryReservationSystemEntities(connectionStringVal))
        {

            Func<MyEntityDataModelEDM.Payment, bool> predicate = (p => p.PaymentID == paymentID);
            payment = myObjectContext2.Payments.SingleOrDefault(predicate);
        }
        return payment;
    }


    public void SaveContextChanges(MyEntityDataModelEDM.Payment paymentEntity)
    {
        using (var myObjectContext = new MyEntityDataModelEDM.LibraryReservationSystemEntities(connectionStringVal))
        {
            myObjectContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }


}


}
```

Client

```
        MyRepository.MyPaymentRepository rep = new MyRepository.MyPaymentRepository();

        MyEntityDataModelEDM.Payment p2= rep.GetPaymentByID(1);
        p2.PaymentType = "TeSSS";
        rep.SaveContextChanges(p2);
```

**READING**

1. Add/Attach and Entity States: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx
2. [Best way to initialize an entity framework context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063730/best-way-to-initialize-an-entity-framework-context)
3. [Entity Framework 4.1: how to work with per call life time data context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164949/entity-framework-4-1-how-to-work-with-per-call-life-time-data-context)
4. [Attaching and detaching entities from context correctly in EF4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678665/attaching-and-detaching-entities-from-context-correctly-in-ef4-1)
5. [Context lifetime management in repository and unit of work pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457275/context-lifetime-management-in-repository-and-unit-of-work-pattern)
6. [Entity Framework Multiple Object Contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693843/entity-framework-multiple-object-contexts)
7. [EF4 - Context.Entry isn't available to change an Entity State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398977/ef4-context-entry-isnt-available-to-change-an-entity-state)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add (if the data is new) or attach (if the data is edited) the object to the context:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx

Something along these lines:

```
public void SaveContextChanges(MyEntityDataModelEDM.Payment paymentEntity)
{
    using (var myObjectContext = new MyEntityDataModelEDM.LibraryReservationSystemEntities(connectionStringVal))
    {
        // use your own logic for determining a "new" entity
        myObjectContext.Entry(paymentEntity).State = 
                (paymentEntity.PaymentID == default(int)) ?  
                               EntityState.Added :
                               EntityState.Modified;

        myObjectContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see the line new MyEntityDataModelEDM.LibraryReservationSystemEntities(). I am creating a new context here, isn't it? How can this context be aware of the change made in previous context object?

Comment: Setting the state to `Modified` tells the context that the entity is modified and should be updated in the database.  It doesn't matter where the object came from.

Comment: I am getting error in this approach. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576911/entity-framework-objectstateentry-error?lq=1